# Adding hours to current date working in local but not working on domain

Tags: php, datetime, time

I tried adding x hours to the current date time in PHP, which works fine on my localhost, but when I deploy the same code on a web server and try it the hours are not added...

Here is my code:

```
$h = 10;
$currenttimestamp =  date("H:i", strtotime("+$h hours", time()));

echo $currenttimestamp;
```

The above code is working fine on localhost which is adding `10hours` to the current datetime, but when hosted on a server it is displaying only current time without adding `10hours`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

**Update:**
PHP version in local: 5.5.11
PHP version on the hosting: 5.4.43

Comment: Yep, that code is ok...

Comment: First question that springs to mind is - what versions of PHP are you running locally vs your production server. You can check with `echo phpversion();`

Comment: Another reason for not using godaddy! [5.4 reached end of life 10 months ago and is no longer supported](http://php.net/eol.php). Switch to a decent host.

Comment: You are using time(), date() and strtotime(). Of these three, latest change was in strtotime(), done in ver 5.3.0 (got that from php manual). So 5.4.43 and 5.5.11 should be the same. Might be a php setup issue at Godaddy's. Refer to them...

Comment: Your code gives the same result for most versions of PHP, but not all. https://3v4l.org/eTb8u

Comment: 5.4.43 and 5.5.11 should give the same results...  As an alternative, I tried to score out **strtotime**, try this: 
**<?php
$h = 10;
$s = 60 * 60 * $h;
$date = date('H:i A', time()+$s); 

echo $date;**

Should give the same results and will not use strtotime() (whats -i'm guessing- is causing trouble at Godaddy). Then leave Godaddy :-)

Comment: It might be a naive guess, but what are the chances that the server and local host have different timezones, can you compare your added +10hrs data with a simple date() with the current time?

Comment: Also, if it's the timezone you're trying to correct, please read [the godaddy help page on Timezone settings](https://nl.godaddy.com/help/why-did-i-receive-a-timezone-error-with-my-php-website-6703) It's for 5.3.x, but might still be the case for 5.4.43.

Comment: werner it is not working.... It is not adding 10 hours

Comment: @Werner  I have been using date_default_timezone_set() this function too, as suggested by godaddy. but still the same issue

Comment: Sorry, typo... **$h = 10; $s = 60 * 60 * $h; $date = date('H:i', time()+$s); echo $date; ** Removed the A. Runs on all versions with same results. Cut and paste on [3v4l](3v4l.org)

Comment: Still think it's GoDaddy causing your issues... ;-) All code posted here should work okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days you should be using the [DateTime collection of classes](http://php.net/datetime), they are far more reliable and easy to use. The equivelent of your code would be something like:-

```
$h = 10;
$currenttimestamp = (new \DateTime())->modify("+$h hours");

echo $currenttimestamp->format('H:i');
```

[This will work on PHP V > 5.4](https://3v4l.org/t2MXd), so should be OK on godaddy, unless the problem is their server settings which has been suggested in comments and is possible.

Comment: Snap! Beat me to it.